# Flask and Pycharm socket.error

Tags: python, flask, pycharm

I am running Flask in Pycharm. Suddenly I can no longer run the framework properly! I get a bunch of error messages that ends with:

```
socket.error: [Errno 48] Address already in use
```

It seems like the socket Flask is using:

```
"http://127.0.0.1:5000/"
```

And it is somehow not available anymore because the last runtime was not shut down properly. I can probably restart my computer and it will probably be a solution, but I don't want to do that if it happens regularly. How do I shut it down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're running Linux, do a `ps aux | grep python` and kill the process that is running flask. If you're running windows, open task manager and kill the python process running flask, but you might have to kill PyCharm.

Comment: Thanks, that worked! In addition, I would point out that when you do {ps aux | grep python} you get a list of all running processes, and the number on the far left (after username) is the process id. You can then do the command: kill processid

Comment: Yes. You could do a `pkill -f <process name>` as well, but picking out the process name isn't always the easiest thing to do.

Answer (score 1):

You can also click the red square button to stop the run (or command-F2 on a mac). If it fails to stop, you'll get a skull icon to kill the process.

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me a few times. I eventually found it to be as simple as to just Run > Stop 'server' in PyCharm.

Answer (score 0):

You want to actively stop the process running your Flask application. [Pycharm documentation describes this.](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/stopping-and-pausing-applications.html) Essentially, Pycharm will run applications internally and keep them running for you, so you can do testing or other tasks. Notably, each debugging run will start it's own process - so shutting these down will release resources.